# Is my rvm directory structure in a weird state?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I don't really know where to turn on this one. Due to an unfortunate situation, I'm in the middle of a rebase which is trying to add ember to a project while upgrading to rails 4.1 and ruby 2.1.1 at the same time (the rails and ruby upgrades were merged into the project while I was on the add ember branch). I'm getting all sorts of dependency errors when trying to get a rails server up.

Some of the errors included:

```
bin/rails:8: warning: already initialized constant APP_PATH
/home/amax/git/forever/bin/rails:8: warning: previous definition of APP_PATH was here

cannot load such file -- websocket/driver

cannot load such file -- active_model_serializers
```

One thing I noticed was that my rvm path has 2.1.1 and 2.1.0 in it which I'm guessing is a bad sign. I'm thinking it may be loading old gems

```
root/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems.....
```

Does anyone know if this could cause problems and any suggestions on a possible remedy?

Comment: you're better off giving us the errors, as this is hard to diagnose.  I had a similar issue and ran `gem pristine --all`.  Unless your gemfile is calling out all the gem versions you might be out of date somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

The errors seemed to change every time and it seemed to be the fault of an irredeemably screwed up gemfile.lock that I caused during the rebase.

I started from a new branch with rails 4.1.1, added ember to it and then copied and pasted that working gemfile.lock over the broken one which resolved all of the issues. If you get into a similar situation I think it may be worth a try to blast away your gemfile and gemfile.lock and recreate them in a stable environment